# How are zombies rankings calculated in Call of Duty: Black Ops 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm quite a fan of Black Ops zombies especially Black Ops 2, and I have currently Rank 4, skull with knife, and I was wondering why I haven't got to rank 5 yet.

[image: Rank Badges]

I used to get taken down a lot in the early games but now with more experience I tend to only go down maybe once/twice per game with 1k kills.

The way I see it, my options are:

- Somehow reset all my stats and start over (by deleting save, etc.)
- Create a new account (not something I want to do)
- Keep grinding (it is even possible at this stage? tips?)

A lot of people suggest to calculate kill/death(down?) ratio, although others say this is not the major player in the rank "algorithm".

My question is how much of a grind I would have to do with the below stats, and if there is any better way to get to shotgun rank in BO2 zombies? I never reached a very high round (40+) so I kinda think it could be related to that.

- Kills: 263988
- Downs: 2529
- Deaths: 1426

[image: Stats summary screen]

Links:

- [Ranking System Explained & How To Rank Up](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=132904305)
- [What KD do you have to have in zombies in order to get shotguns?](https://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/what-kd-do-you-have-to-have-in-zombies-in-order-to-get-shotguns.974353/)

Comment: From my understanding based on what I found, the rank is almost like an average.  In which case, Once you get so far (as you have), it becomes very difficult if not impossible to level up further.

Comment: that's my fear. I'm somehow hopeful that there is a "trigger" I am missing such as a specific high round. I think that's how I moved to knife, after a great game with some randoms in town. it can't be from insufficient kills like many pointed out and KD ratio, although a good pointer, doesn't seem to be a 100% direct relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jimmy Zielinski](https://twitter.com/ZielinskiJimmy) (former Treyarch Director BO1 & BO2 Zombies) made the following [tweet](https://twitter.com/ZielinskiJimmy/status/390862987038191616) back in 17 Oct 2013:

> "The Ra k is ive", it ris and lls bas on ho ll y pl erall. I is ba on
> w ma dow ver y fin nd. Low nd dow cou aga y mo th dow in lat nds..."

This slightly hidden message actually means:

> The Rank is alive, it rises and falls based on how well you play
> overall. It is based on how many downs versus your final round. Low
> round downs counts against you more than downs in later rounds.

Further reading:

[Ranking System Confirmed!](https://www.thetechgame.com/Archives/t=6066933/ranking-system-confirmed-read.html)

[Jimmy Z Explains Rank](https://www.reddit.com/r/CODZombies/comments/1onhvr/jimmy_z_explains_rank/)

Answer (score 0):

It is based off rounds to downs. To get the shotgun you are required to have a round to down ratio of 20:1. The knife is earned at 13:1.

[image]